# How do X-wings maneuver in space and in the atmosphere?

Tags: star-wars

I want to know how do X-wings maneuver in space and in the atmosphere? In normal spaceflight, spacecraft use RCS (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reaction_control_system), separate sets of thrusters to provide attitude control. Another thing is that the X-wing's wings are too far back making it unbalanced, plus the wings are not curved, providing no lift.

How do these things even remotely fly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- **Atmosphere Lift**:

  The lift is provided by a combination of Repulsorlifts and the wings's lift. Source: Star Wars Technical Journal #3.

  [image]

  Interestingly, the wing's aren't required in Star Wars fighters - you'll notice that Tie-Fighters also can maneuver in atmosphere  (*source: Disney canon novel "Aftermath"*) despite having no lift surfaces at all.
- **Wing Shape and lift**

  Specifically to address your "flat wings don't lift" concern: someone [asked this on Quora](https://www.quora.com/Whats-wrong-with-an-X-wing-aircraft-in-real-life), and a real expert (Jamie Gull, Aerospace Engineer at SpaceX and Scaled Composites) answered:

  > **A flat airfoil can create lift at a non-zero angle of attack, it does not need to be a shaped foil**. Flat surface lift is an into aerodynamics problem, even a pizza box can fly as a wing given the right propulsion and controls.
- **Maneuvers**

  In space, maneuvering is achieved is done using [Etheric rudder](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Etheric_rudder). It was introduced in X-Wing novels by Michael A. Stackpole, but how it works was never explained.

Comment: Though I think it's worth mentioning that the TIE design maneuvers very poorly while in atmosphere compared to while in vacuum. This could be due to its lack of horizontal wings.